# Moderate content using HTTP DELETE

Tags: rest, http, httprequest

For a platform using a mostly-RESTful HTTP API to moderate many types of content, I am wondering if having clients call DELETE on the same endpoint they used to create the content makes sense.

The API would identify the client as either the content's creator, a platform moderator, or a regular user.

In the case of the first two, the content would be immediately deleted, but in the case of the regular user, the content would be flagged for review and essentially be deleted only for that user.

This is as opposed to POSTing to /flag and /remove endpoints for each type of content as this requires additional routes and other overhead.

Update: The real question here is:
Does it make sense to use HTTP DELETE to moderate content in the way described? Will that lead to future complications?

Comment: It will be easier to understand your problem if you add an actual question. What exactly is your problem?

Comment: @PedroWerneck. Thanks I suppose I should have made it more obvious, the question is in the first sentence:

"I am wondering if having clients call DELETE on the same endpoint they used to create the content makes sense."

To reword: Does it make sense to use HTTP DELETE to moderate content in the way described? Will that lead to future complications?

Comment: Then do it. You can edit your question.

Comment: @PedroWerneck That's exactly what I did :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm assuming clients created the content by a PUT request to an endpoint of their choice.

From the client viewpoint, I don't see any obvious problems with the approach. In fact, this is exactly how DELETE is intended to be used in remote authoring applications, but there are some minor issues that depend on how much information you want the clients to have.

Do you want the regular user to know his resource is flagged for deletion, or do you want that to be completely transparent? If the first, the DELETE request should return `202 Accepted` and some description of the status, and a further GET request might inform the client of the pending deletion in some way. If you don't care about that, you can simply return `404 Not Found` or `410 Gone`, but then you might have to deal with the possibility of the client creating new content for the same endpoint while the deletion is still pending. That might be a problem or not, depending on your implementation of the PUT semantics.

Comment: Thanks for your help!